# Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare() Android. Loop in a timer

Tags: java, android, time

I'm trying to receive message from my php server by creating a thread in a service but it doesnt work. can't go in the while loop and the error message as title shows. Please Help.

```
            //Set the schedule function and rate
            Timer t = new Timer();
            t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {


                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



                            }

                        });
                    }

                    private void runOnUiThread(Runnable runnable) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        String flag = receivermessage();
                        while (flag.equals("N")){
                            notifyUser();
                        }
                        Log.d(TAG, "Download Successful");
                    }



            }, 0, 10000);
```

Comment: use a synctask http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Can I make asynctask in the thread so that i keep extracting data in the php server in a certain period of time?

Comment: you should always load asynctask from the ui thread

Comment: Any Skeleton code as a reference to me? I am still not able to make it work atm...

Answer (score 0):

better to use asynctask and receive msg inside asynctask doinbackground() mtd.As webservice call may take more time that u can't block main thread for more than 5sec in android.